# 415-Unsupported-Media-Type when posting a form using ajax to a ASP.NET Core 3.1 controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, unobtrusive-validation, asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 based project where I validate forms using jQuery-Unobtrusive and [jQuery-Unobtrusive-AJAX](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax/unobtrusive-ajax). When the form is submitted, I get an HTTP 415 error.

Follow is my controller's code.

```
[Route("api/[controller]"), ApiController]
public class ScheduleController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IEmailSender Emailer;

    public ScheduleController(IEmailSender emailer)
    {
        Emailer = emailer;
    }

    [HttpPost(Name = "Schedule"), ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> Schedule([FromBody]Schedule viewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Problem(false);
        }

        bool sent = await Emailer.SendEmailAsync("Schedule Request", viewModel.GetMessage());

        return Ok(sent);
    }
}
```

Here is a stripped-down version of my form

```
<form asp-route="Schedule" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-begin="onBegin" data-ajax-failure="onFailed" data-ajax-success="onSuccess">
@* fields... *@
</form>
```

I tried changing the `[FromBody]` to `[FromForm]` and tried removing it completely but nothing seems to be fixing this error.

Here is the raw request header

```
Host: localhost:1234
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Length: 330
Origin: https://localhost:1234
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: [Removed from simplicity]
```

Here is the raw request body

```
PropertyId=123&Date=4%2F11%2F2020+12%3A00%3A00+AM&Time=4%2F10%2F2020+11%3A00%3A00+AM&Phone=(123)+456-7890&Email=&__RequestVerificationToken=CfDJ8K77JmNhv79HurCngEMVfZh4LUSvtnAQfHGD3p3cO5bsB1NgI--P5JuhfG62F5igdXq2ers_V7MoMDFNVQTVuF9qGqTslDTkDPdcqIFD4wUkREhD6vHvSrdbqT24LWXTfr9Nu124A2OVAlJZa_xLCvs&X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest
```

Answer (score 8):

> The HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type client error response code indicates that the server refuses to accept the request because the payload format is in an unsupported format.
>
> The format problem might be due to the request's indicated Content-Type or Content-Encoding, or as a result of inspecting the data directly.

When your `Content-Type` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` you must change `[FromBody]` to `[FromForm]`.

If you use `[FromForm]` add `[Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]` on action to accept `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content-type

```
[Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
[HttpPost(Name = "Schedule"), ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> Schedule([FromForm]Schedule viewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Problem();
    }

    bool sent = await Emailer.SendEmailAsync("Schedule Request", viewModel.GetMessage());

    return Ok(sent);
}
```

**ConfigureService**

```
services.AddMvc(config =>
    {
        // Add XML Content Negotiation
        config.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
        config.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;
        config.InputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerInputFormatter());
        config.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
    });
```

this [link](https://code-maze.com/content-negotiation-dotnet-core/) maybe helpful for you.

if you need use the `[FromBody]` you must change `Content-Type` to `application/json` instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: As you can see in my question, I attempted to use `[FromForm]` attribute but that also did not work. I also manually tried adding `Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")` attribute and that also led to the same 415 error

Comment: @John i updated my answer .Check **ConfigureService** method.